# AutoHotkey #IfWinNotActive not activating

Tags: autohotkey

I like having my middle mouse button be a double click, so I have an `.ahk` script to make that happen, but a lot of programs I use (particular ones involving a 3D environment like Autodesk stuff) need the middle mouse button to function normally, so I have this script:

```
#SetTitleMatchMode,  2
#IfWinNotActive, Autodesk 
MButton::send, {LButton}{LButton}
```

All this does is make the double click work constantly. As if it's ignoring the WinNotActive completly. I have no idea why this doesn't work. I've tried a few things to see if I could fix it myself, but I made no progress.

*Please remember that kind and respectful responces are greatly appreciated.*

Comment: can you please elaborate on "doesn't work"? Is `MButton`s functionality overridden everywhere?

Comment: Sorry I was going to add more details, but I forgot. It's fixed now.    There is another MButton function mentioned, but it only activates under specific conditions and shouldn't interfere with anything.

Comment: it might interfere.. try finishing the code snippet with a plain `#ifwinnotactive` so the condition is "reset" after the MButton Hotkey

Comment: I added the `#IfWinNotActive` at the end and worked, @Blauhirn! Thanks. You should add that as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Context-sensitive directives apply to all following hotstrings and hotkeys. Thus, you have to "reset" this behaviour and limit the scope with another `#ifWinNotActive`:

```
#SetTitleMatchMode,  2
#IfWinNotActive, Autodesk 
MButton::send, {LButton}{LButton}
#IfWinNotActive
```

(see https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/_IfWinActive.htm#Basic_Operation for details)

Comment: Yay! It works, the only issue now is that I have multiple programs that I want to trigger this, and I the ahk_group doesn't seem to function here.

Comment: okay I don't know ahk_group. But you can use `#if !winActive("Autodesk") && !winActive("prog2") && !winActive("prog3")` and so on if you wish, so you can fit it all in one line (also dont forget to close the section with another `#if`)

Comment: That's not working for me for some reason. I noticed that you used `&&` instead of `||` so I tried `||` but it didn't change anything.

Comment: no, my coide snipped could be read as "if  Autodesk is not active and prog2 is not active and prog3 is not active". I don't know why i t wouldnt work. maybe with extra braces like `#if (!winActive("Autodesk") && !winActive("prog2") && !winActive("prog3"))`. however, if that dont work, I cant help you any further

Comment: Okay, somehow I left `SetTitleMatchMode` out of the code. It works now. Thank you!